# ClassCastException when mocking a casted object that returns nothing

Tags: java, casting, mocking, mockito

I'm rather new to java and I'm wondering if someone could point me in the correct direction.
I'm trying to mock (using mockito) a method that has the following code:

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
channel.setInputStream(null);
```

I get a ClassCastException on the line:

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
```

The exception is as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$15aeab7e cannot be cast to com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec
```

Here is my unit test:

```
    @Test
public void testExecuteSSHCommand() throws JSchException, IOException {
    Channel channel = mock(Channel.class);
    ChannelExec channelExec = mock(ChannelExec.class);

    String command = "dummyCommand";
    String result = "the correct result";
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));;

    when(channel.getInputStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
    when(session.openChannel("exec")).thenReturn(channel);
    //when(channel.setCommand(command)).get();

    logger.info("Returning {}", sshClient.executeSSHCommand(session, command));
    assertEquals(result, sshClient.executeSSHCommand(session, command));
}
```

Channel is an abstract class and ChannelExec is a pojo

Comment: Sounds like a simple typo. You are returning the **wrong** object in your spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want openChannel to return a ChannelExec

```
 Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
 ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
```

you need to specify that

```
when(session.openChannel("exec")).thenReturn(channelExec);
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't see the wood for the trees there

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
when(session.openChannel("exec")).thenReturn(channelExec);
```

There is a discrepancy because you are currently returning a mock of an abstract class and try to cast it to one of its impl.